# How can I determine the current php array number

Tags: php, arrays

Good Afternoon.

I'm attempting to make an array list with one of the key values being ($_REQUEST['qty#']), where "#" would be the current number of the item within the array (as it pertains to a field in a form that gathers this info).

For example:

```
$itemdetails =  array(
    array(
    'qty' => ($_REQUEST['qty1']),
    'price' => 0.70,
    'pn' => 'TV-1000',

    array(
    'qty' => ($_REQUEST['qty2']),
    'price' => 0.99,
    'pn' => 'TV-5000'));
```

Is there any way that I can automatically have the number in ($_REQUEST['qty']) be determined without having to type in the numbers manually?

Just wondering. My next guess would be to enter it all into a database and pull it from there.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: You say that the current number of the item would be from a form or something. Is there anywhere where you have access to the actual #'s? Or is it always going to be a specific number range every time? Need a bit more context here.

Comment: Why don't you just use a counter or write a special class with a function called getCurrent or similar and use that to the get the current element?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to loop ...

```
$itemdetails = array(
        array(
                'price' => 0.70,
                'pn' => 'TV-1000'
        ),

        array(
                'price' => 0.99,
                'pn' => 'TV-5000'
        )
);

foreach ( $itemdetails as $k => &$item ) {
    $item['qty'] = $k + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is pass an array of data via POST/GET.

To do this in your inputs, you make the name value = `qty[]` for each input.  Note the array syntax `[]` here.

PHP will automatically take all values for input with that array syntax and build an array out of it in $_POST/$_REQUEST.

So you would be able to access your array like

```
var_dump($_POST['qty']);
var_dump($_REQUEST['qty']);
```

That however still doesn't give the ability to match this to the price/pn as you need.  So, let's take the array syntax one step further and actually put a key value in it like this:

```
<input name="qty[0]" ... />
<input name="qty[1]" ... />
```

By doing this you will be able to know exactly which array index matches which item (assuming you know the order the inputs were displayed in).

The would make `$_POST['qty'][0]` be the first item, `$_POST['qty'][1]` be the next and so on.

So assuming you also have you prices/pn in an array like this:

```
$item_array = array(
    0 => array('price' => 123, 'pn' = 'ABC'),
    1 => array('price' => 456, 'pn' = 'XYZ'),
    ...
);
```

You could then easily loop through the input quantities and build you final array like this:

```
$itemdetails = array();
foreach ($_REQUEST['qty'] as $key => $value) {
    $itemdetails[$key] = $item_array[$key];
    $itemdetails[$key]['qty'] = $value;
)
```

Also note, that if you are expecting this data to be passed via POST, it is considered best practice to use the `$_POST` superglobal rather than the `$_REQUEST` superglobal.